# Tracking data changes

Tags: php, mysql, database, tracking

I work on a market research database centric website, developed in PHP and MySQL.
It consists of two big parts – one in which users insert and update own data (let say one table T with an user_id field) and another in which an website administrator can insert new or update existing records (same table).

Obviously, in some cases end users will have their data overridden by the administrator while in other cases, administrator entered data is updated by end users (it is fine both ways).

The requirement is to highlight the view/edit forms with (let’s say) blue if end user was the last to update a certain field or red if the administrator is to “blame”.

I am looking into an efficient and consistent method to implement this.

So far, I have the following options:

- For each record in table T, add another one ( char(1) ) in which write ‘U’ if end user inserted/updated the field or ‘A’ if the administrator did so. When the view/edit form is rendered, use this information to highlight each field accordingly.
- Create a new table H storing an edit history containing something like user_id, field_name, last_update_user_id. Keep table H up-to-date when fields are updated in main table T. When the view/edit form is rendered, use this information to highlight each form field accordingly.

What are the pros/cons of these options; can you suggest others?

Comment: With "record", do you mean row or column?

Comment: Sorry Jakob for the confusion, I meant to say column; I will edit to reflect this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose it just depends how forward-looking you want to be.

Your first approach has the advantage of being very simple to implement, is very straightforward to update and utilize, and also will only increase your storage requirements very slightly, but it's also the extreme minimum in terms of the amount of information you're storing.

If you go with the second approach and store a more complete history, if you need to add an "edit history" in the future, you'll already have things set up for that, and a lot of data waiting around. But if you end up never needing this data, it's a bit of a waste.

Or if you want the best of both worlds, you could combine them. Keep a full edit history but also update the single-character flag in the main record. That way you don't have to do any processing of the history to find the most recent edit, just look at the flag. But if you ever do need the full history, it's available.

Personally, I prefer keeping more information than I think I'll need at the time. Storage space is very cheap, and you never know when it's going to come in handy. I'd probably go even further than what you proposed, and also make it so the edit history keeps track of *what* they changed, and the before/after values. That can be very handy for debugging, and could be useful in the future depending on the project's exact needs.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, implement an audit table that holds copies of the historical data, by/from whom &c.  I work on a system currently that keeps it simple and writes the value changes as simple name-value string pairs along with date and by whom.  It requires mandatory master record adjustment, but works well for tracking.  You could implement this easily with a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to audit data changes is through a trigger on the database table. In your case you may want to just update the last person to make the change. Or you may want a full auditing solution where you store the previous values making it easy to restore them if they were made in error. But the key to this is to do this on the database and not through the application. Database changes are often made through sources other than the application and you will want to know if this happened as well. Suppose someone hacked into the database and updated the data, wouldn't you like to be able to find the old data easily or know who did it even if he or she did it through a query window and not through the application? You might also need to know if the data was changed through a data import if you ever have to get large amounts of data at one time.

Comment: A db trigger sounds like the software isn't well designed or regulated. I espouse lighter weight on the data side, and centralizing logic like this within the app.

Comment: Databases do not accessed only from applications, auditing is to monitor all database acccess even that which came from unofficial sources. If you do auditing at the application, you will lose the records of things that are changed on an ad hoc basis (fix these 2000 records), imports, people committing fraud who have direct table access but not admin rights, etc. It isrisky and unprofessional to not do this in the database and has nothing at all to do with how well the application is designed.